# Finding a value in the range

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a subroutine that looks through a range of cells starting in cell A1 (the range is 1 column wide) containing String values. My sub first finds the entire range and assign it to a Range variable "theForest" to help make searching easier. Then, it looks through each cell in the range until it finds the word “Edward”. If he is found or not, it display the result in a message (stating that he was or was not found).

The code I have so far is this:

```
With Range("A1")
     'this will help find the entire range, since it is only one column I will search by going down
   theForest = Range(.Offset(0,0), .End(xlDown)).Select
   Dim cell As Range
   For Each cell In theForest
        If InStr(Edward) Then
            Msgbox"He was found"
        Else
            Msgbox"He was not found sorry"
        End If
   Next cell
End With
```

However I am getting numerous errors upon running the program and I think the issue is with the

```
theForest = Range(.Offset(0,0), .End(xlDown.)).Select
```

line of code. I would appreciate any guidance into this simple code.

Thank you :)

EDIT: Here is some new code I have come up with:

```
Dim isFound As Boolean
isFound = False
With Range("A1")
    For i = 1 to 500
        If .Offset(1,0).Value = "Edward" Then
            isFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
If isFound = True Then
    Msgbox " Edward was found"
Else
    MsgBox "Edward was not found"
End if
```

Then again it does not include finding the entire range and assiging it to the range variable theForest.

Comment: It looks like a pop-up box will appear for every cell in the range.  Is this the desired behaviour?  (btw, you have an extra `.` at the end of your `xlDown`)

Comment: @lebelinoz , no just want the popup box to appear after it is done searching.

Comment: The "InStr(Edward)" line doesn't make sense, either.  Can you edit the question to include working code?

Comment: Remove the `.Select` at the end of that line.  Plus the others' comments.

Comment: I have editted the OP, it seems correct but it does not include finding the entire range and assigning it to the range variable theForest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Dim theForest as Range, f as Range


 Set theForest = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), _
                                     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

 Set f = theForest.Find("Edward", lookat:=xlWhole) 

 If Not f Is Nothing Then
      Msgbox"He was found"
 Else
     Msgbox"He was not found sorry"
 End If
```